# Oracle populate a table with an IDENTITY column

Tags: sql, oracle, identity

I have a partitioned table,  which I'm trying to populate with the following SQL code. It appears to work fine when I dont have the seq_num column.

Since the seq_num IDENTITY column generates its own value what do I need to do to populate the table with the seq_num in place?

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (     
     seq_num NUMBER  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   dt   DATE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(7,'DAY'))
(
   PARTITION OLD_DATA values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
);
/

INSERT into t1
with dt (dt, interv) as (
select date '2022-01-01', numtodsinterval(30,'MINUTE') from dual
union all
select dt.dt + interv, interv from dt
where dt.dt + interv < date '2022-01-15')
select dt from dt;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "populate"? With what? Definition is quite clear: `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` which means when no value provided.

Comment: I want an automated sequential number associated with each time. How can I make my INSERT statement work with the seq_num.

Comment: Just specify all the columns except `seq_num` in the `insert` statement: `insert into t1 (dt) select ...`

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you populate statement with giving date only, `seq_num` will be generate automatic.

```
insert into t1 (dt) 
select dt from dt
```